# JMeter: Does JMeter do Connection pooling for webserice(Http) call for 5.2.1

Tags: jmeter, connection-pooling

I have a webservice under test with tps simulation of 1000tps. There is a single thread group. Does it do connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, each JMeter thread (virtual user) starts a new HTTP [connection](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).

Whether the connection is being re-created on each iteration and its time to live is being controlled by the following [JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/):

- `httpclient4.time_to_live`
- `httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration`

and `Same user on each iteration` setting of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) itself:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I see one more post that says Jmeter supports Connection pooling. So new connection is applicable for webservice calls only? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843921/does-jmeter-pool-http-connections#:~:text=JMeter%20does%20some%20pooling%20of,connections%20are%20pooled%20per%2Dthread.&text=1%2C%20JMeter%20uses%20an%20instance%20of%20SimpleHttpConnectionManager%20on%20each%20thread.

Comment: Internal pooling is for simulating browser-like behaviour, for example [downloading embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses), standard JMeter Thread Group doesn't create connection pool available for all virtual users